# PHP error when trying to login to GetSimple CMS

Tags: php, html, authentication

I am getting a PHP error when trying to authenticate when logging in to a CMS back end. I have recently moved the site to a different host and it isn't authenticating. 
I am a noob at php so go easy on me. Also any suggestions for a php guide or book to read would be great.

Here is the error:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/home/ob1/domains/******.com.au/public_html/data/cache/c21343136c4fd5bdee8b0e6679c78ea6.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/ob1/domains/******.com.au/public_html/admin/inc/template_functions.php on line 1062

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/ob1/domains/*****.com.au/public_html/admin/inc/template_functions.php on line 1063
```

Comment: Check your folder permissions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `.../public_html/data/cache/` has, at the minimum, file permissions (`chmod`) of 775, but some scripts require the full 777.

Additionally, its giving a chomd error for a different file. I suspect that would be due to a owner-ship issue. Basically, it's trying to chmod a file or folder (probably the folder above) to something and doesn't have the correct ownership to do so. But, that may be a failsafe of the script to attempt to correct the issue itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i just ended up reinstalling the CMS anyway, it was moved over to a different domain and was having lots of problems.